# Modern example of picklist?

Tags: interaction-design, interface, user-centered-design

I am trying to find modern implementations of the picklist. The main benefits of this ui being the ability to see all selections at once in order to add/subtract them from a group. This kind of interaction reminds me of old windows based software but the functionality remains important today. I have not been able to find a modern pattern for this. Anyone know of anything?

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with this version? Why do you want a 'modern' one? Just do this but with Material Design style and bingo - modern version.

Comment: How many items are in your list?

Answer (score 4):

The example you're providing might work well if you have the space for it, but something like [Chosen](http://julesjanssen.github.io/chosen/) could work even better.

In the example below, Chosen is the version on the right:

[image: chosen]

This should also be rather intuitive to users, since this is how e.g. email clients behave when adding recipients.

Comment: This is a good suggestion if you are okay with users typing. Pocket tagging on Android works like this.